# Не работают счетчики символов в строке c#

Tags: c#, строки

Я не программист, как вы поняли, но для общего развития основы программирования преподают, в одном из листингов надо было переписать, приведенный ниже код и запустить. Проблема в следующем: Где условия цифра либо буква для элемента строки, счетчики dcounter и wcounter не работают, выводят 0 и якобы букв и цифр одинаково. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    namespace example_3
    {
        class Program
        {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte dcounter = 0,
            wcounter = 0;
        string stroka;
        int i;
        using (StreamReader MyFile = new StreamReader("test.txt"))
        {
            while ((stroka = MyFile.ReadLine())!=null){
                Console.WriteLine(stroka);
                i = 0;
                while (i < stroka.Length){
                    while ((i < stroka.Length)&&(char.IsLetterOrDigit(stroka, i))){
                        i++;
                    }
                       if ((i < stroka.Length)&&(char.IsDigit(stroka, i)))
                           dcounter++;
                    while ((i < stroka.Length)&&(char.IsDigit(stroka, i))){
                        i++;
                    }
                    if ((i < stroka.Length)&&(char.IsLetter(stroka, i)))
                        wcounter++;
                    while ((i < stroka.Length)&&(char.IsLetter(stroka, i))){
                        i++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        if (wcounter > dcounter){
            Console.Write("Групп букв больше");
            Console.WriteLine("{0}>{1}", wcounter, dcounter);
        }
        else if (dcounter > wcounter){
            Console.Write("Групп цифр больше");
            Console.WriteLine("{0}>{1}", dcounter, wcounter);
        }
        else {
            Console.Write("Групп букв и букв одинаково");
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", wcounter, dcounter);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: А задача то в чем? Что должен делать этот код? Покажите пример текста и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: А вы разберитесь в логике внутри второго while. Она, скажем так, экзотическая. Проще циклом for пройтись по символам считанной строки.